# Is it possible to use multiple Hay Day accounts on one iOS device in 2015?

Tags: ios, game-center, hay-day

I wish to share my iPad with my daughter. This is the only device I played on. We're both connected to Facebook accounts.

Will my account be kept in the cloud connected to my Facebook account, or will it be saved with Game Center? Will I be able to log out of Facebook, log in with another Facebook account, and play on a new farm?

I'm suspicious because I've googled up that some people had troubles with Hay Day accounts. Few of those mention Facebook, but apparently most of the problems are from pre-Facebook era. Also, the warning message mentions that the old farm will be erased.